# Default Value for Field with Python Expression in Function Editor

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes, default-value

I have a line shapefile in QGIS with several columns and the values for many of those columns could be automatically calculated and updated depending on certain other fiels.

Now, I came across the default value option in the layer properties and I tried to build a Python function that automatically generates the value, but for some reason I do not manage to automatically get the value from the field that will serve as the argument for the function.

So, after saving the function, I try the expression

```
defaultPrice("Type")
```

I just get an error, although this is how I would usually apply functions when I manually update a field (like `lower("Type")` or whatever).

So, I have the field `"Type"` which has the values `Gardentrench`, `Asphalt`, `Brick Pavement`, `As Built`, `HDD`, `Crossing and Grass`. I have another field `"PricePerMe"` where I assign the cost of the `"Type"` per Meter. Not even calculated, just the price per one meter.

This is the code that I wrote:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def defaultPrice(Type, feature, parent):
    if Type == 'Gardentrench':
        price =  12.5
    elif Type == 'Grass':
        price =  15
    elif Type == 'As Built':
        price = 1
    elif Type == 'Asphalt':
        price =  30
    elif Type == 'Brick Pavement':
        price =  100
    elif Type == 'HDD':
        price =  250
    elif Type == 'Crossing':
        price =  90
    else:
        price = 0
    return price
```

In the expression field, I would like to trigger this function by

```
defaultPrice("Type")
```

and update this value. In the attribute table when I update a field value or values of a column, it does display me down a correct preview value, but after running it, there are no changes in the `"Type"` column:

[image]

In the default value expression editor I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Looked at some examples that I found, but couldn't really apply any of them to my problem, although I am sure it's very trivial.

Edit:
Quick note: I know how to use virtual fields and that would do also, but they are not saved in the shapefile, only in the project file and I would like to learn something new.

Comment: Field name might be `type` instead of `Type`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine here. Columns must be in double quoting like you do.

You must use the **Field Calculator** not the Expression editor for updating you table.

[image]

Your way of doing it is fine, if your just playing around. A problem like this should be based on table relations and not Python, where you have a separate table for the prices. A lot easier to maintain and keep prices updated, by your or a auto process.

BTW my type column is made and written in small letters, since I used to using PostgreSQL.

**Update**

In regard to your comment: The expression function does not run as a default value. If you look in Fields and Values it just says NULL when the Expression editor is opened from the Default value UI. I believe this is an error in QGIS.

But you should use a virtual field instead anyways. If you save a default style for your layer QGIS will regenerate the virtual field for you, when you open the table. It is dangerous using Default values since things (prices) could change. I never use Default values only virtual fields, actually I don't use any of it since it is possibly within relational databases also.

Comment: So there is no way to automatically make QGIS update that Price Field except with a Virtual Field? I was hoping to use this Default Value feature :)

Comment: Made an update to answer.

Comment: Too bad but good to know. In the course of this issue I at least got to know the Python function feature that I never used before :D Using the virtual layer is certainly no problem, I just wanted something "more fixed" or "engraved" in the shapefile. And something that does that automatically :)